# Create .CSV File in Android application

Tags: android, csv

How can create **.csv** file in android application, in which we will store some data like some employe details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

download library from   [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/)

and jar file add to your application.

Inside your application do

```
     CSVWriter writer = null;
try 
{
    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/myfile.csv"), ',');
    String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#"); // array of your values
    writer.writeNext(entries);  
    writer.close();
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
    //error
}
```

Comment: u there, and can help for that using this code, the file only read only, I wan to give the permission  for read & write, how can I do that...

Comment: If I want to append the data in same csv how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own implementation for example using String.format or [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/MessageFormat.html), you can use a template engine like [StringTemplate](http://stringtemplate.org/) or you can use tools like [Bindy](http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html).

Example using bindy:

```
@CsvRecord(isOrdered = true)
public Class Order {

   @DataField(pos = 1, position = 11)
   private int orderNr;

   @DataField(pos = 2, position = 10)
   private String clientNr;

...
}
```

I'm not sure you can use bindy without camel-core, if not then it's probably a dependency you don't want in an Android app ;)

There are loads of other [options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2053816/404536) as well.