# How to create a .csv on android

Tags: android

My aim is to create a .csv file from a table, to print a report. I can then store this .csv file into my sdCard. I have referred to some questions similar to this but they ask a jar file to be present. Is there any other way without a jar file to be integrated?

Have integrate a jar file in the component au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter...What I dont find here is the logic to write into a new line...Help?

Comment: Use `java.io` classes - especially BufferedWriter/BufferedReader.

Comment: which questions you have referred?

Comment: AVD, that would be a tedious job, right?

Comment: Paresh, one among them is this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561749/create-csv-fie-in-android-app

Comment: [Android - Generate CSV file from table values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632501/android-generate-csv-file-from-table-values)

Comment: Thanks Paresh, I was referring to the lib you just sent....

Comment: Paresh, I did look into it...but am stuck with which jar to import?

Comment: Paresh, I think I got the jar file now.....looking at the way to implement it...

Comment: Paresh, New line in the jar file that youve mentioned

Answer (score 25):

After searching lots over internet i got solution of creating Csv file inside android App, 
internal storage (without SD Card), So i decided to share with others how to create csv file in android & How to attach it with mail.

First Download `Opencsv.jar` library and add to your android project. https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/files/opencsv/

**Add the implementation directly (no download of `.jar`)**

```
implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6' // Here is opencsv library
```

**Or add jar file in android project :**

1. Change Android Studio file structure Android to Project ( At Top Left below of Project Name Android,change to Project)
2. Copy `opencsv.jar` file and paste in `libs` folder.
3. Right click `opencsv.jar` file and hit `Add as library`.

**Add permission to Menifest.xml**( If device API is 23 or greater Check RunTime Permission)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Open **build.gradle (Module:app)** and check it added :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/opencsv-4.1.jar') // Here is opencsv library added to project when using .jar
}
```

Now coding part : **Creating csv file and inserting data into it.**

```
 String csv = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyCsvFile.csv"); // Here csv file name is MyCsvFile.csv


 //by Hiting button csv will create inside phone storage.
 buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            CSVWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

                    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                    data.add(new String[]{"Country", "Capital"});
                    data.add(new String[]{"India", "New Delhi"});
                    data.add(new String[]{"United States", "Washington D.C"});
                    data.add(new String[]{"Germany", "Berlin"});

                    writer.writeAll(data); // data is adding to csv 

                    writer.close();
                    callRead();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Now if you want to **view your csv file inside the android** follow below steps:

1. Go to File Manager/ My Files to your phone.
2. Go to internal storage/ Local , just scroll you will get your csv file.
3. If csv file is not opening in your device install [Csv Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.shira.csv.viewer&hl=en) from Play Store.

Now, If you want to attach this csv file to your app with attachment

**Here is the code for attachment of csv file in mail :**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email@example.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject here");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text");

                File file = new File(csv);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Pick an Email provider"));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Don't forget to turn on the permission of the app from Android Phone Settings >> Apps >> *your app name* >> (Title = App Settings) Permissions >> Turn on Storage on --> Bingo! The file can be saved - Samsung Note 8 worked on me with commenting the code line " callRead(); " Idk why..

Comment: Its perfectly working for me..I just removed .getAbsolutePath() and rest it worked fine.;)  Thank you..

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding @tenTen

Comment: Awesome Explanation... Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 15):

check below code to generate CSV file. no need to use jar file.

you have to save one csv file in to SD-CARD.

[Sample CSV FILE](http://s374326078.onlinehome.us/foursquare/web/a.csv)

```
public void exportEmailInCSV() throws IOException {
        {

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Folder");

            boolean var = false;
            if (!folder.exists())
                var = folder.mkdir();

            System.out.println("" + var);


            final String filename = folder.toString() + "/" + "Test.csv";

            // show waiting screen
            CharSequence contentTitle = getString(R.string.app_name);
            final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    MailConfiguration.this, contentTitle, "even geduld aub...",
                    true);//please wait
            final Handler handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {




                }
            };

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);

                        Cursor cursor = db.selectAll();

                        fw.append("No");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("code");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("nr");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("Orde");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("Da");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("Date");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("Leverancier");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("Baaln");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("asd");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("Kwaliteit");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append("asd");
                        fw.append(',');

                        fw.append('\n');

                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                fw.append(cursor.getString(0));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(1));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(2));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(3));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(4));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(5));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(6));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(7));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(8));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(9));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append(cursor.getString(10));
                                fw.append(',');

                                fw.append('\n');

                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                            cursor.close();
                        }

                        // fw.flush();
                        fw.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    progDailog.dismiss();
                }
            }.start();

        }

    }
```

add this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: it's not wroking when string containg space.

Comment: not using jar is just reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 3):

this will work :)

```
    try {
    String TestString="";

    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

       // Write the string to the file
     for( i=1; i<total_row; i++)
        {

            for( j=1; j<total_col; j++)
            {
                TestString+=table[i][j].getText().toString();        // to pass in every widget a context of activity (necessary) 
                TestString += " ,";
            }
             TestString+="\n";
        }
     Log.v("the string is",TestString);
     osw.write(TestString);
     osw.flush();
     osw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) 
      {ioe.printStackTrace();}
```

in manifest u would have to write

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

just before the application tag

Comment: Khurram, sorry pal...am a noob......I did not understand your comment.. // to pass in every widget a context of activity (necessary) 
                TestString += " ,"; there is no widget here???

Comment: Hey table[][] is a 2d array of Edit text. That line is getting data from every cell of that 2d array and storing it in form of strings :)

Comment: and after every string it appends a 'comma'just as a csv works

Comment: thanks for your time Khurram, but have taken a different approach

Comment: You might not be aware of this, but commas within a CSV field have to be escaped. If one of those values contains a comma, it'll screw up whoever reads the CSV next.