# How to get data from Excel file to Android application?

Tags: java, android, excel, import

Is it possible to get data from Excel to my Android application? if yes, how? or is there any other alternative or better suggestions. What I want to happen here in my app is that I will have a button that will import Excel's data to my app because I want to use that data from Excel to my app. By the way, I'm new to Java and Android.

Comment: When you used a search engine to search for `java excel library`, what did you learn?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reflect Data in the Excel sheet to the android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669391/reflect-data-in-the-excel-sheet-to-the-android-app)