# ANDROID - get csv from phone files then pass to php server via volley

Tags: php, android, csv, file-upload

Good day. Before anything, I would like to say that I have tried searching. However, what I could find is only reading the CSV that is inside the `raw` resource folder inside `res`.

What I would like to do is have a `Button` then it will prompt the user to find the csv file inside the user's phone files, then 'upload' it inside the application. The application will then parse and read it then send it to php in my server via volley for inserting to the database.

I am only a student and is quite new to Android Development so this might be a pretty obvious thing already but I do not know what to find. Please bear with me and I thank you for taking the time to help me. It is for my school project.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get csv file from android device.

```
String csv = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyCsvFile.csv"); // Here csv file name is MyCsvFile.csv
```

For More,

- How to create Csv. inside Android Device.
- Insert Data into it, Retrieve it & attach into mail,

**Look into this:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643905/8448886

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering.
Is this a code that can make me choose a csv from any directory inside the phone?

Comment: i have not tested  yet, you can check but it will get from your internal device.@RFA

Comment: No. This is not code to let the user pick a file. Its not a file picker or file browser.