# sensor data saving at CSV file

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope, sensor-fusion

I am new in android developing, I developed this code based on previous code related to Mr.liwatiz to find orientation from sensor fusion, I added writeCSV file to store data, The application work and the file created but there is no data store! So please what is the problem. my code clear below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{
private SensorManager mSensorManager = null;

    // angular speeds from gyro
    private float[] gyro = new float[3];

    // rotation matrix from gyro data
    private float[] gyroMatrix = new float[9];

    // orientation angles from gyro matrix
    private float[] gyroOrientation = new float[3];

    // magnetic field vector
    private float[] magnet = new float[3];

    // accelerometer vector
    private float[] accel = new float[3];

    // orientation angles from accel and magnet
    private float[] accMagOrientation = new float[3];

    // final orientation angles from sensor fusion
    private float[] fusedOrientation = new float[3];

    // accelerometer and magnetometer based rotation matrix
    private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];

    public static final float EPSILON = 0.000000001f;
    private static final float NS2S = 1.0f / 1000000.0f;
    private int timestamp;
    private boolean initState = true;

    public static final int TIME_CONSTANT = 30;
    public static final float FILTER_COEFFICIENT = 0.98f;
    private Timer fuseTimer = new Timer();

    // The following members are only for displaying the sensor output.
    public Handler mHandler;
    private RadioGroup mRadioGroup;
    private TextView mAzimuthView;
    private TextView mPitchView;
    private TextView mRollView;
    private int radioSelection;
    DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("#.##");


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gyroOrientation[0] = 0.0f;
        gyroOrientation[1] = 0.0f;
        gyroOrientation[2] = 0.0f;

        // initialise gyroMatrix with identity matrix
        gyroMatrix[0] = 1.0f; gyroMatrix[1] = 0.0f; gyroMatrix[2] = 0.0f;
        gyroMatrix[3] = 0.0f; gyroMatrix[4] = 1.0f; gyroMatrix[5] = 0.0f;
        gyroMatrix[6] = 0.0f; gyroMatrix[7] = 0.0f; gyroMatrix[8] = 1.0f;

        // get sensorManager and initialise sensor listeners
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        initListeners();

        // wait for one second until gyroscope and magnetometer/accelerometer
        // data is initialised then scedule the complementary filter task
        fuseTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new calculateFusedOrientationTask(),
                1000, TIME_CONSTANT);

        // GUI stuff
        mHandler = new Handler();
        radioSelection = 0;
        d.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        d.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
        d.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
        mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        mAzimuthView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        mPitchView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        mRollView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // unregister sensor listeners to prevent the activity from draining the device's battery.
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // unregister sensor listeners to prevent the activity from draining the device's battery.
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // restore the sensor listeners when user resumes the application.
        initListeners();
    }

    // This function registers sensor listeners for the accelerometer, magnetometer and gyroscope.
    public void initListeners(){
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }



    public void writeToCsvGy(String x,String y,String z) throws IOException {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TollCulator");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        if (success) {
            // Do something on success



            String csv = "/storage/sdcard0/project/GyroscopeValue.csv";
            FileWriter file_writer = new FileWriter(csv,true);




            String s= c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+","+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+","+c.get(Calendar.DATE)+","+c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+","+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+","+c.get(Calendar.SECOND)+","+ c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)+","+x + ","+y+","+z+"\n";

            file_writer.append(s);
            file_writer.close();
        }


    }

















    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                // copy new accelerometer data into accel array and calculate orientation
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, accel, 0, 3);
                calculateAccMagOrientation();
                break;

            case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
                // process gyro data
                gyroFunction(event);
                break;

            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                // copy new magnetometer data into magnet array
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, magnet, 0, 3);
                break;
        }
    }

    // calculates orientation angles from accelerometer and magnetometer output
    public void calculateAccMagOrientation() {
        if(SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accel, magnet)) {
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, accMagOrientation);
        }
    }

    // This function is borrowed from the Android reference
    // at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values
    // It calculates a rotation vector from the gyroscope angular speed values.
    private void getRotationVectorFromGyro(float[] gyroValues,
                                           float[] deltaRotationVector,
                                           float timeFactor)
    {
        float[] normValues = new float[3];

        // Calculate the angular speed of the sample
        float omegaMagnitude =
                (float)Math.sqrt(gyroValues[0] * gyroValues[0] +
                        gyroValues[1] * gyroValues[1] +
                        gyroValues[2] * gyroValues[2]);

        // Normalize the rotation vector if it's big enough to get the axis
        if(omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
            normValues[0] = gyroValues[0] / omegaMagnitude;
            normValues[1] = gyroValues[1] / omegaMagnitude;
            normValues[2] = gyroValues[2] / omegaMagnitude;
        }

        // Integrate around this axis with the angular speed by the timestep
        // in order to get a delta rotation from this sample over the timestep
        // We will convert this axis-angle representation of the delta rotation
        // into a quaternion before turning it into the rotation matrix.
        float thetaOverTwo = omegaMagnitude * timeFactor;
        float sinThetaOverTwo = (float)Math.sin(thetaOverTwo);
        float cosThetaOverTwo = (float)Math.cos(thetaOverTwo);
        deltaRotationVector[0] = sinThetaOverTwo * normValues[0];
        deltaRotationVector[1] = sinThetaOverTwo * normValues[1];
        deltaRotationVector[2] = sinThetaOverTwo * normValues[2];
        deltaRotationVector[3] = cosThetaOverTwo;
    }

    // This function performs the integration of the gyroscope data.
    // It writes the gyroscope based orientation into gyroOrientation.
    public void gyroFunction(SensorEvent event) {
        // don't start until first accelerometer/magnetometer orientation has been acquired
        if (accMagOrientation == null)
            return;

        // initialisation of the gyroscope based rotation matrix
        if(initState) {
            float[] initMatrix = new float[9];
            initMatrix = getRotationMatrixFromOrientation(accMagOrientation);
            float[] test = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(initMatrix, test);
            gyroMatrix = matrixMultiplication(gyroMatrix, initMatrix);
            initState = false;
        }

        // copy the new gyro values into the gyro array
        // convert the raw gyro data into a rotation vector
        float[] deltaVector = new float[4];
        if(timestamp != 0) {
            final float dT = (event.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S;
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, gyro, 0, 3);
            getRotationVectorFromGyro(gyro, deltaVector, dT / 2.0f);
        }

        // measurement done, save current time for next interval

        switch ( timestamp = (int) event.timestamp ) {
        }

        // convert rotation vector into rotation matrix
        float[] deltaMatrix = new float[9];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaMatrix, deltaVector);

        // apply the new rotation interval on the gyroscope based rotation matrix
        gyroMatrix = matrixMultiplication(gyroMatrix, deltaMatrix);

        // get the gyroscope based orientation from the rotation matrix
        SensorManager.getOrientation(gyroMatrix, gyroOrientation);
    }

    private float[] getRotationMatrixFromOrientation(float[] o) {
        float[] xM = new float[9];
        float[] yM = new float[9];
        float[] zM = new float[9];

        float sinX = (float)Math.sin(o[1]);
        float cosX = (float)Math.cos(o[1]);
        float sinY = (float)Math.sin(o[2]);
        float cosY = (float)Math.cos(o[2]);
        float sinZ = (float)Math.sin(o[0]);
        float cosZ = (float)Math.cos(o[0]);

        // rotation about x-axis (pitch)
        xM[0] = 1.0f; xM[1] = 0.0f; xM[2] = 0.0f;
        xM[3] = 0.0f; xM[4] = cosX; xM[5] = sinX;
        xM[6] = 0.0f; xM[7] = -sinX; xM[8] = cosX;

        // rotation about y-axis (roll)
        yM[0] = cosY; yM[1] = 0.0f; yM[2] = sinY;
        yM[3] = 0.0f; yM[4] = 1.0f; yM[5] = 0.0f;
        yM[6] = -sinY; yM[7] = 0.0f; yM[8] = cosY;

        // rotation about z-axis (azimuth)
        zM[0] = cosZ; zM[1] = sinZ; zM[2] = 0.0f;
        zM[3] = -sinZ; zM[4] = cosZ; zM[5] = 0.0f;
        zM[6] = 0.0f; zM[7] = 0.0f; zM[8] = 1.0f;

        // rotation order is y, x, z (roll, pitch, azimuth)
        float[] resultMatrix = matrixMultiplication(xM, yM);
        resultMatrix = matrixMultiplication(zM, resultMatrix);
        return resultMatrix;





    }

    private float[] matrixMultiplication(float[] A, float[] B) {
        float[] result = new float[9];

        result[0] = A[0] * B[0] + A[1] * B[3] + A[2] * B[6];
        result[1] = A[0] * B[1] + A[1] * B[4] + A[2] * B[7];
        result[2] = A[0] * B[2] + A[1] * B[5] + A[2] * B[8];

        result[3] = A[3] * B[0] + A[4] * B[3] + A[5] * B[6];
        result[4] = A[3] * B[1] + A[4] * B[4] + A[5] * B[7];
        result[5] = A[3] * B[2] + A[4] * B[5] + A[5] * B[8];

        result[6] = A[6] * B[0] + A[7] * B[3] + A[8] * B[6];
        result[7] = A[6] * B[1] + A[7] * B[4] + A[8] * B[7];
        result[8] = A[6] * B[2] + A[7] * B[5] + A[8] * B[8];

        return result;
    }

    class calculateFusedOrientationTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            float oneMinusCoeff = 1.0f - FILTER_COEFFICIENT;

            /*
             * Fix for 179? <--> -179? transition problem:
             * Check whether one of the two orientation angles (gyro or accMag) is negative while the other one is positive.
             * If so, add 360? (2 * math.PI) to the negative value, perform the sensor fusion, and remove the 360? from the result
             * if it is greater than 180?. This stabilizes the output in positive-to-negative-transition cases.
             */

            // azimuth
            if (gyroOrientation[0] < -0.5 * Math.PI && accMagOrientation[0] > 0.0) {
                fusedOrientation[0] = (float) (FILTER_COEFFICIENT * (gyroOrientation[0] + 2.0 * Math.PI) + oneMinusCoeff * accMagOrientation[0]);
                fusedOrientation[0] -= (fusedOrientation[0] > Math.PI) ? 2.0 * Math.PI : 0;
            }
            else if (accMagOrientation[0] < -0.5 * Math.PI && gyroOrientation[0] > 0.0) {
                fusedOrientation[0] = (float) (FILTER_COEFFICIENT * gyroOrientation[0] + oneMinusCoeff * (accMagOrientation[0] + 2.0 * Math.PI));
                fusedOrientation[0] -= (fusedOrientation[0] > Math.PI)? 2.0 * Math.PI : 0;
            }
            else {
                fusedOrientation[0] = FILTER_COEFFICIENT * gyroOrientation[0] + oneMinusCoeff * accMagOrientation[0];
            }

            // pitch
            if (gyroOrientation[1] < -0.5 * Math.PI && accMagOrientation[1] > 0.0) {
                fusedOrientation[1] = (float) (FILTER_COEFFICIENT * (gyroOrientation[1] + 2.0 * Math.PI) + oneMinusCoeff * accMagOrientation[1]);
                fusedOrientation[1] -= (fusedOrientation[1] > Math.PI) ? 2.0 * Math.PI : 0;
            }
            else if (accMagOrientation[1] < -0.5 * Math.PI && gyroOrientation[1] > 0.0) {
                fusedOrientation[1] = (float) (FILTER_COEFFICIENT * gyroOrientation[1] + oneMinusCoeff * (accMagOrientation[1] + 2.0 * Math.PI));
                fusedOrientation[1] -= (fusedOrientation[1] > Math.PI)? 2.0 * Math.PI : 0;
            }
            else {
                fusedOrientation[1] = FILTER_COEFFICIENT * gyroOrientation[1] + oneMinusCoeff * accMagOrientation[1];
            }

            // roll
            if (gyroOrientation[2] < -0.5 * Math.PI && accMagOrientation[2] > 0.0) {
                fusedOrientation[2] = (float) (FILTER_COEFFICIENT * (gyroOrientation[2] + 2.0 * Math.PI) + oneMinusCoeff * accMagOrientation[2]);
                fusedOrientation[2] -= (fusedOrientation[2] > Math.PI) ? 2.0 * Math.PI : 0;
            }
            else if (accMagOrientation[2] < -0.5 * Math.PI && gyroOrientation[2] > 0.0) {
                fusedOrientation[2] = (float) (FILTER_COEFFICIENT * gyroOrientation[2] + oneMinusCoeff * (accMagOrientation[2] + 2.0 * Math.PI));
                fusedOrientation[2] -= (fusedOrientation[2] > Math.PI)? 2.0 * Math.PI : 0;
            }
            else {
                fusedOrientation[2] = FILTER_COEFFICIENT * gyroOrientation[2] + oneMinusCoeff * accMagOrientation[2];
            }

            // overwrite gyro matrix and orientation with fused orientation
            // to comensate gyro drift
            gyroMatrix = getRotationMatrixFromOrientation(fusedOrientation);
            System.arraycopy(fusedOrientation, 0, gyroOrientation, 0, 3);


            // update sensor output in GUI
            mHandler.post(updateOreintationDisplayTask);
        }
    }


    // **************************** GUI FUNCTIONS *********************************

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch(checkedId) {
            case R.id.radio0:
                radioSelection = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.radio1:
                radioSelection = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.radio2:
                radioSelection = 2;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void updateOreintationDisplay() {
        switch(radioSelection) {
            case 0:
                mAzimuthView.setText(d.format(accMagOrientation[0] * 180/Math.PI) + '?');
                mPitchView.setText(d.format(accMagOrientation[1] * 180/Math.PI) + '?');
                mRollView.setText(d.format(accMagOrientation[2] * 180/Math.PI) + '?');



                try {
                    writeToCsv((d.format(accMagOrientation[0] * 180/Math.PI) + '?'),(d.format(accMagOrientation[1] * 180/Math.PI)+ '?'),(d.format(accMagOrientation[2] * 180/Math.PI) + '?'));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                break;
            case 1:
                mAzimuthView.setText(d.format(gyroOrientation[0] * 180/Math.PI) + '?');
                mPitchView.setText(d.format(gyroOrientation[1] * 180/Math.PI) + '?');
                mRollView.setText(d.format(gyroOrientation[2] * 180/Math.PI) + '?');

                try {
                    writeToCsv((d.format(gyroOrientation[0] * 180/Math.PI) + '?'),(d.format(gyroOrientation[1] * 180/Math.PI)+ '?'),(d.format(gyroOrientation[2] * 180/Math.PI) + '?'));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




                break;
            case 2:
                mAzimuthView.setText(d.format(fusedOrientation[0] * 180/Math.PI) + '?');
                mPitchView.setText(d.format(fusedOrientation[1] * 180/Math.PI) + '?');
                mRollView.setText(d.format(fusedOrientation[2] * 180/Math.PI) + '?');



                try {
                    writeToCsv((d.format(fusedOrientation[0] * 180/Math.PI) + '?'),(d.format(fusedOrientation[1] * 180/Math.PI) + '?'),(d.format(fusedOrientation[2] * 180/Math.PI) + '?'));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private void writeToCsv(String x, String y, String z)  throws IOException {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

       // File path = getFilesDir();

        File folder = new File(getFilesDir() + "/TollCulator");
        boolean success = true;
        if (! folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        if (success) {
            // Do something on success



            String csv = "data.csv";
            FileWriter file_writer = new FileWriter(csv,true);




            String s= c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+","+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+","+c.get(Calendar.DATE)+","+c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+","+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+","+c.get(Calendar.SECOND)+","+ c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)+","+x + ","+y+","+z+"\n";

            file_writer.append(s);
            file_writer.close();
        }


    }

    private Runnable updateOreintationDisplayTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateOreintationDisplay();
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code to create csv file and save data into csv.

**Reference :** https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/files/opencsv/

**For more :** [Look into this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643905/8448886)

```
 String csv = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyCsvFile.csv"); // Here csv file name is MyCsvFile.csv


 //by Hiting button csv will create inside phone storage.
 buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            CSVWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

                    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                    data.add(new String[]{"Country", "Capital"});
                    data.add(new String[]{"India", "New Delhi"});
                    data.add(new String[]{"United States", "Washington D.C"});
                    data.add(new String[]{"Germany", "Berlin"});

                    writer.writeAll(data); // data is adding to csv 

                    writer.close();
                    callRead();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```