# Writing to a CSV file that already exists in the project

Tags: java, android, csv, storage

I have 2 CSV's files currently saved in the raw folder within my Android Project. The reason I have these is that I have 2 `AutoCompleteTextView` fields which read from these CSV files.

The thing is as time goes on these CSV files will be come outdated. So what I would like to achieve is that if the value entered does not exist in the CSV file then it is added to it.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

[image: CSV Files]

Write Code:

```
public void exportEmailInCSV() throws IOException {
    {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Folder");
        boolean var = false;
        if (!folder.exists())
            var = folder.mkdir();
        final String filename = folder.toString() + "/" + "Test.csv";
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
            fw.append(batchNumber);
            Toast.makeText(this, "SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Read Code:

```
 public void ReadInCSV() throws IOException {
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Batchnumbers");
        final String filename = folder.toString() + "/" + "BatchNumbers";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename + ".csv"));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, sCurrentLine, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null) br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AutocompleteTextView code:

```
//READ FROM ITEM CODES CSV
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.itemcodesofficial));
    List<String> listitemcodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scanner2.hasNext()) {
        listitemcodes.add(scanner2.next());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listitemcodes );
    itemcodetextview.setAdapter(adapter2);
    scanner2.close();
```

Comment: you are tring to edit csv in raw folder? then its not possible. you can copy those files to internal memory and append with new values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341931/how-to-create-a-csv-on-android

Comment: Thanks @GeorgePJ. It is now writing to a CSV file. Could you advise me on how I can copy and paste values into internal storage? and it also seems to be replacing the value instead of adding a new one when I save.

Comment: Can you show me the code you are using to write file?

Comment: Added above :)!

Comment: @GeorgePJ it isn't replacing it, its adding it to the end, when really I want that to be a separate entry?

Comment: separate entry means? new line?

Comment: yeap because I want to read these back to my AutocompleteTextView

Comment: try    fw.append("\n"); before write

Comment: instead of .csv files, why you don't make a database with 2 tables. On first time run, copy data from raw to it (there are some great tuts for it). Word insertion/deletion/update will be much ease for you then.

Comment: that worked @GeorgePJ. Thanks samirk433 I will have a look at ha

Comment: @GeorgePJ. Whats the best way to read these back to AutcompleteTextView? I have added the code I am using to read back and how I am populating the autocomplete

Comment: @Aaron use AsyncTask to read file, make array list of entries and return arraylist. then use arraylist received on `onPostExecute()` to populate autocomplete

Comment: @Aaron if my comments helpful to you please mark it as useful