# generate csv file and email as attachment

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

i am trying to generate Csv file and at the same time send it as an attachment on the email. it shows attachment when sending via email but the problem is when i check the inbox i only find email with no attachment. i will appriciate your help.

Here is the code that i have tried

```
 buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

        textTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);
        textSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
        textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String to = textTo.getText().toString();
                String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
                String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("plain/text");
                File data = null;
                try {
                    Date dateVal = new Date();
                    String filename = dateVal.toString();
                    data = File.createTempFile("Report", ".csv");
                    FileWriter out = (FileWriter) GenerateCsv.generateCsvFile(
                            data, "Name,Data1");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(data));
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "E-mail"));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public class GenerateCsv {
        public static FileWriter generateCsvFile(File sFileName,String fileContent) {
            FileWriter writer = null;

            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
                writer.append(fileContent);
                             writer.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally
            {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return writer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you have any joy with this? i'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

It is seen, your GenerateCsv is not functioning, you have to import csv library. In your code there is no any. To download check this: [Csv library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561749/create-csv-fie-in-android-app)

And also see: [Read/Write csv](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/491823/Read-2fWriteplusCSVplusinplusplusAndroid)

and permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```